# Как наложить картинку на header?

Tags: html, css

Как мне такое сделать? (картинку на header)
[image]

Код моей шапки:

```html
<header class="d-flex justify-content-around p-3 align-items-center">
    <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="">
    <div class="nav-links d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="nav-link"><img src="img/search.svg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="nav-link"><img src="img/cart.svg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="nav-link"><a href="#" class="signup">Sign up</a></div>
        <div class="nav-link"><a href="#" class="signin">Sign in</a></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: может не надо думать как впихать картинку именно в шапку, и в целом поразмышлять куда ее стоит добавить?

Comment: @teran вообще, думал о том чтобы её вставить в блок ниже, но как её потом на header "задвинуть"?

Comment: Вопрос такой - при скролле меню будет фиксированное к верху страницы или нет? от этого зависит как можно реализовать ваш пример

Comment: @klifort нет, нефиксированное

Comment: Я б `header` оставил как есть а блок с картонкой и текстом добавил следующим, и к нему добавил `margin-top` c минусовым значением высоты блока `header`

Comment: @klifort это действительно оказалось очень просто, спасибо, буду набираться опыта)

Answer (score 0):

Если `header` `position: static` (т.е. не должен прилипать к верху экрана), то просто разбейте блок на две части. Пример на bootstrap:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container row">
  <div class="col col-md-auto">
    <img src="https://static2.gazeta.ua/img2/cache/gallery/984/984368_1_w_590.jpg?v=0" width="300">
  </div>
  <div class="col py-2">
    <header>
      <h2>Header</h2>
    </header>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```